# I am running my application which is based java spring boot framework. but getting this error. Can you help me to resolve this error?

Tags: java, spring-boot

**I am running my application which is based  java spring boot framework. basically i have more then one  microservices and I want them to communicate using http rest .
but getting this error. Can you help me to resolve this error??**

```text
2022-01-10 10:31:52.834  INFO 13740 --- [           main] com.accounts.account.AccountApplication  : Started AccountApplication in 53.129 seconds (JVM running for 57.978)
2022-01-10 10:31:53.259 DEBUG 13740 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2022-01-10 10:31:53.274 DEBUG 13740 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2022-01-10 10:32:42.838  INFO 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-10 10:32:42.838  INFO 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-10 10:32:42.839 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2022-01-10 10:32:42.840 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2022-01-10 10:32:42.841 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2022-01-10 10:32:42.848 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@72a61e61
2022-01-10 10:32:42.850 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@742dbac8
2022-01-10 10:32:42.851 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2022-01-10 10:32:42.852  INFO 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 13 ms
2022-01-10 10:32:42.942 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2022-01-10 10:32:43.030 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-01-10 10:32:43.046 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-01-10 10:32:43.069 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2022-01-10 10:32:43.071 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-01-10 10:32:43.072 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2022-01-10 10:32:43.144 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2022-01-10 10:32:43.229 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2022-01-10 10:32:43.231 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-01-10 10:32:43.750 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2022-01-10 10:32:43.790 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2022-01-10 10:32:43.791 DEBUG 13740 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

[image: IDE screen shot]

Comment: Looks like you’re calling `GET /`, what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: the details of customer based on customer id

Comment: Your code clearly states `@PostMapping(“/myAccount”)`. So both the verb and the path are wrong in that case.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it seems you are trying to retrieve an account based on the customer id. In that case, it will be @GetMapping and not @PostMapping ( at line 12). Also , in case of get, we pass the variables in the url and not in the request body.
As a coding practice, the className should start with a  capital letter ( the return type of your method should be Account and not accounts )

```
@GetMapping("/myAccount/{id}


public Account AccountsGetAccountDetails(@PathVariable String id ) {}
```

Comment: Much as your points are valid, I believe the actual error is reported while the OP is trying to access the route `GET "/"` returning a `404 NOT FOUND` error response. I would suggest you supplement your answer with a reason attributed to the `404` response reported in the OP's terminal image screenshot.